# Error: Sys.ScriptLoadFailedException: The script contains multiple calls to Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded(). Only one is allowed

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, telerik

I am using telerik(2013.2.717.35) radpivot grid inside the tab in share point webpage.I just cleared the cookies in IE browser then refresh the page.After clearing cookies of the IE then I received the following java script error,

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Timestamp: Sat, 15 Mar 2014 10:49:26 UTC

Message: Sys.ScriptLoadFailedException: The script 'url/ScriptResource.axd?d=NLsb5woRKng3QSqxBfT3iMlldZuQb2Wgz7gHimErJa0wiuizx1S44OOpe4XfxUIhIt8mQcKrJ9iMBozXwR7hMne2pfQVhwBUygJ3GtZR-DzQksIrdhUcsSiRe0vR0rHuZOJUWyeJZD8A2y9SlZmi1w2&t=ffffffffbb3a0828' contains multiple calls to Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded(). Only one is allowed.
Line: 5
Char: 45397
Code: 0
URI:" url/ScriptResource.axd?d=rbfZGRRw9gI6cqyylLz78ZWmUM7t-t3E6WWYrljZnlN9vC4Ljs40KHVIpstIssYpKwky7IvAMQ8ZOflEyAl6a3x1QUFtpJd3O6_HXHCz0xY1&t=ffffffffec2d9970"

If I refresh the page again ,It works fine.I am using partial update panel to load multiple controls in the page.I have installed share point 2010 with service pack 2.It occurs only If I have tab and pivotgrid in the same page.See the screen shot to review the error.

[image]

Regards,

Ranjithkumar.G

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AJAX as advised here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/radajaxmanager-in-webpart-on-sharepoint-2010?

Also, upgrade to the latest of the Telerik controls, a lot of fixes have been made for the 8 months since your version.

You can also try using [their CDN](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager-cdn-support.html) to avoid webresources issues from the current server.